# CSS and div problem

Tags: css

in my web application I have this css rules:

```
/*Header*/
#headerAbs{
    background-color: #63554c;
}

#headerAbs .header1{
    float: left;
}

#headerAbs .header2{
    float: right;
}
```

and this HTML code:

```
<div id="headerAbs">
     <img class="header1" src="../../../../imagenes/header.jpg" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
     <img class="header2" src="../../../../imagenes/logoUsal.png" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
</div>
```

My problem is that the `<img>` elements are well styled (if I change the float, they move), but the `<div>` background is not changing.

I'm using firebug, and if I inspect the element, `<div id="headerAbs">` is not highlighted, that means that for some reason is not taken in mind. The same problem with another element in my application.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `headerAbs` is only becoming large enough to show the images, if those are the same height then you wont be able to see `headerAbs` through them thus not seeing the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements inside your `div` are floated, so your `div` has null height. You still can:

- Set explicit value for CSS `height` property of your `div`;
- Add `clear: both;` block inside your `div` after floated elements;
- Flush your floated elements (so called *float context*) by adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent of them (`#headerAbs { overflow: hidden; }`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/*Header*/
#headerAbs{
    background-color: #63554c;
}

#headerAbs .header1{
    float: left;
}

#headerAbs .header2{
    float: right;
}



<div id="headerAbs">
   <img class="header1" src="../../../../imagenes/header.jpg" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
   <img class="header2" src="../../../../imagenes/logoUsal.png" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
   <div style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Previously the div had no height while the two images were in it because they are positioned using float. It's a weird quirk of CSS but after some practice you will get used to it. You can see the difference for yourself if instead of setting the background-color, try setting the border. You will notice that until you add the div to clear both, the border will just look like a line because the div has no height.

Here's the link where I first learned about this strange problem:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

### Edit

I decided to just take quick screen shots and show you myself for anyone who might come across this page through google. I modified the source of the page to look like the following, and got this output:

```
/*Header*/
#headerAbs{
/*    background-color: #63554c; */
    border: solid 5px red;
}

#headerAbs .header1{
    float: left;
}

#headerAbs .header2{
    float: right;
}

<div id="headerAbs">
   <img class="header1" src="../../../../imagenes/header.jpg" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
   <img class="header2" src="../../../../imagenes/logoUsal.png" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
</div>
```

[image: screen shot of original problem]

Then, after implementing the fix I suggested above, here's the new result:

```
/*Header*/
#headerAbs{
/*    background-color: #63554c; */
    border: solid 5px red;
}

#headerAbs .header1{
    float: left;
}

#headerAbs .header2{
    float: right;
}

<div id="headerAbs">
   <img class="header1" src="../../../../imagenes/header.jpg" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
   <img class="header2" src="../../../../imagenes/logoUsal.png" alt="ARVC-UMH" />
   <div style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

[image: screen shot with fix]

Hope that helps!

Comment: with <div style="clear:both;" /> I get the whole page with that backgroun. Thanks for the link, anyway!

Comment: Very interesting your edit. It'll be very useful for many people, I'm sure. Thanks again

Comment: @BlancaHdez Hmm... that seems a bit odd. Something else must be going on as well. Either way, hopefully you found some information to at least help you in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I usually add overflow: hidden to a parent element. In your case it will be:

```
#headerAbs {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #63554c;
}
```